# Why do I have to add '/Content/' to uris when using Url.ContentUri?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

Why do I have to add `/Content/` to the uri when using `Url.Content`? What's the method useful for? :) Am I missing something?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/StyleSheets/screen.css") %>" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx):

> Converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

If your content is in the /Content directory, you'll need to include it.  Not all content exists in the /Content directory.  For instance in the app I'm working on at the moment, javascript lives in /scripts, so we use

```
Url.Content("~/scripts/xyz.js");
```

Which translates the virtual path to the application absolute path.

Since the app may be installed at the root of a webserver, or within a directory, you never know if an absolute path is safe.  Using this method takes care of this.

Comment: The name should have been a bit more generic then, since MVC projects have "Content" folder by default.